# Pilha par e pilha impar erro de lógica

Tags: c

Pessoal tenho esse código abaixo, funciona, só que está estranho, ele não imprime a última posição.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM_PILHA 2
#define NUM_ENTRA 5

void empilha(int *pilha, int *topo, int valor)
{
if (*topo < TAM_PILHA)
{
    pilha[*topo] = valor;
    (*topo)++;
}
else
{
    printf("Pilha Cheia\n");
}
}

int desempilha(int *pilha, int *topo)
{
if (*topo > 0)
{
    (*topo)--;
    return pilha[*topo];
}
else
{
    printf("Pilha Vazia\n");
}
}

int main()
{
int pilha_par[TAM_PILHA], pilha_impar[TAM_PILHA], topo_par = 0, topo_impar = 0;
int i = 0, num_do_usuario = 0;
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRA; i++)
{
    printf("\nEntre com um numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_do_usuario);

    if ((num_do_usuario % 2) == 0)
    {
        empilha(pilha_par, &topo_par, num_do_usuario);
    }
    else
    {
        empilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar, num_do_usuario);
    }
}

printf("\n\nNumeros pares sao: ");
while (topo_par > 0)
{
    printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_par, &topo_par));
}

printf("\n\nNumeros impares sao: ");
while (topo_impar > 0)
{
    printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar));
}

printf("\n\n");

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pra mim está funcionando, claro que havia um erro e nem compilava: http://ideone.com/qD47TT

Comment: Aqui tem hora que chega até a 3 pergunta e vc digita o número já dá pilha cheia. E tem hora que pergunta as 5 vezes, o que está certo, e não imprime o último número que digito.

Comment: De fato na forma feita se mudar os `define` pode dar algum problema, o código não é nada robusto.

Comment: Digita primeiro o número 3, depois 4, 2 e 6, já vai da pilha cheia! Sendo que não era pra dar, tem que ir até o quinto vetor, o último vetor e imprimir o último vetor também, o último vetor não imprime na tela.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na sua função `empilha` troquei o sinal de `<` para `<=` dentro do `for (i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRA; i++)`.

Entrada:

```
Entre com um numero: 1 
Entre com um numero: 2 
Entre com um numero: 3
Entre com um numero: 4 
Entre com um numero: 5
```

Saída:

> Numeros pares sao: 4 2
>
> Numeros impares sao: 5 3 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM_PILHA 2
#define NUM_ENTRA 5

void empilha(int *pilha, int *topo, int valor)
{
    if (*topo <= TAM_PILHA)
    {
        pilha[*topo] = valor;
        (*topo)++;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Pilha Cheia\n");
    }
}

int desempilha(int *pilha, int *topo)
{
    if (*topo > 0)
    {
        (*topo)--;
        return pilha[*topo];
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Pilha Vazia\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int pilha_par[TAM_PILHA], pilha_impar[TAM_PILHA], topo_par = 0, topo_impar = 0;
    int i = 0, num_do_usuario = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRA; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEntre com um numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &num_do_usuario);

        if ((num_do_usuario % 2) == 0)
        {
            empilha(pilha_par, &topo_par, num_do_usuario);
        }
        else
        {
            empilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar, num_do_usuario);
        }

    }

    printf("\n\nNumeros pares sao: ");
    while (topo_par > 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_par, &topo_par));
    }

    printf("\n\nNumeros impares sao: ");
    while (topo_impar > 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar));
    }

    printf("\n\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/TB0gzX).

Comment: Aqui aconteceu assim: primeiro digitei o número 1, 2, 3, 4 e 5, a saída foi: números pares: 4 e 5 - números ímpares: 5 3 e 1. Tá errado isso.

Comment: @ThiagoFerreira, não sei o motivo de no seu estar diferente, até testei em outro compilador e apareceu corretamente. Veja: 
https://goo.gl/7xu317

Comment: Estou testando pelo codeblocks, tenta por ele que vc vai vê a diferença, de fato pelo seu compilador online aí deu certo, mas ainda no compilador online ai, se vc digitar: 65, 43, 23 e 5 já vai pilha cheia.

Comment: Amigo deu certo apenas no Visual Studio. No code blocks eu não consegui. Vou abrir uma nova perguntando sobre isso.

Answer (score 2):

Não tem nada de errado no código. Coloquei alguns `printf()` para mostrar o que está acontecendo.

A pilha está enchendo mesmo. Coloca 1 item em impar, depois coloca 1 em par, depois coloca um segundo em par, portanto os 2 elementos que a pilha pode ter já foi atingido, aí tenta colocar o terceiro e dá pilha cheia, então coloca outro valor na pilha impar enchendo-a e encerra. Tudo dentro da normalidade. Se quer colocar 3 pares e não encha a pilha, aumente o tamanho dela para 3. Ou tente só colocar 2 elementos em cada pilha.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM_PILHA 2
#define NUM_ENTRA 5

void empilha(int *pilha, int *topo, int valor) {
    printf("%d na posição %d ", valor, *topo);
    if (*topo < TAM_PILHA) {
        pilha[*topo] = valor;
        (*topo)++;
    } else {
        printf("Pilha Cheia\n");
    }
}

int desempilha(int *pilha, int *topo) {
    if (*topo > 0) {
        (*topo)--;
        return pilha[*topo];
    } else {
        printf("Pilha Vazia\n");
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int pilha_par[TAM_PILHA] = { 0 }, pilha_impar[TAM_PILHA] = { 0 }, topo_par = 0, topo_impar = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ENTRA; i++) {
        int num_do_usuario = 0;
        printf("\nEntre com um numero: ");
        scanf("%d", &num_do_usuario);
        if (num_do_usuario % 2 == 0) {
            printf("Vai entrar na pilha   par: ");
            empilha(pilha_par, &topo_par, num_do_usuario);
        } else {
            printf("Vai entrar na pilha impar: ");
            empilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar, num_do_usuario);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\nNumeros pares sao: ");
    while (topo_par > 0) {
        printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_par, &topo_par));
    }
    printf("\n\nNumeros impares sao: ");
    while (topo_impar > 0) {
        printf("%d ", desempilha(pilha_impar, &topo_impar));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/qD47TT). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/japwiahn-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/StackFull.c).